# How to encourage turkeys onto my land without encouraging other wild life?

Tags: animals

I am a homesteader. When I first moved to my property, I started a gaggle of turkeys and for about two years regularly fed them in the morning. It was nice because my kids got to see them and around the holiday season I was able to have a nice meal for my family. I used to be able to have turkey to eat as opposed to having to go to the grocery store.

They have since vanished, my guess would be neighbors also hunting them, natural predators, etc.

What I would like to do is encourage the turkeys that I see roaming on the other side of the river to stop by regularly. I have thrown corn on my side of the river with no luck. I imagine turkeys might not like to cross rivers.

Is there a good method to get the turkeys onto my land? I have considered building a bridge, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: How does this relate to sustainable living?

Comment: @LShaver Well I am a homesteader. Sustainable living and homesteading are one in the same. What is your definition of sustainable living?

Comment: I agree, and wasn't trying to challenge you -- however for the purposes of this site we ask that you include in your question how it relates to sustainable living, as per [the site help section](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I see. Well I used to be able to have turkey to eat as a pose to having to go to the grocery store. Is that a good reason or should I delete this question. I don't want to cause trouble. Just thought I found a site that fits my lifestyle. My bad.

Comment: Nope, no trouble at all! You can [edit your question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/posts/6278/edit) to include that info, as well as your comment on homesteading. Being specific about how the things we discuss here relate to sustainability makes the site a more valuable resource for others who have similar questions (which, you might say, is more *sustainable*).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your best bet is to start another gaggle.  Wild turkeys are capable of flight, but aren't built for long distance flying.   Much depends on the width of the river.  If it's only a few feet, I would expect them to cross.

Work on habitat for them.  Put out patches of corn on your side of the river.

Make sure there are trees where they can roost at night.  Talk to your local wildlife people and find out what shrubs and trees will make it a better place for turkeys.